# Multiply signal with carrier frequency in matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency, mixing, multiplication, carrier

I have an input complex signal at frequency of 250.01MHz. i have to mix this signal with a frequency at 250MHz. I understand that by mixing(multiplying) it will produce the sum and difference of the 2 frequencies. And i will use a low pass filter to filter out the sum frequencies. However, i cant seem to get how to multiply the signal with the frequency, Someone please help me. Below is my code:

```
close all;clear all;
    j=sqrt(-1);
    fsig = 250.01e6; %input frequency
    fs = 1e6; %sampling frequency
    fc = 250e6; %frequency of USRP
    t= [0:1/fs:1];
    sig = exp(j*2*pi*fsig*t); %input signal
```

Comment: Want to shift the signal in frequency domain?

Comment: Hi mehmet, I only want to keep the difference between the 2 frequencies. But I need to write it out in code such that it can show me the sum and differences.

Comment: Wait a minute. Are you really sampling a 250 MHz carrier with 1 Msamples/second? Unless you are consciously doing [bandpass sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undersampling), this doesn't seem appropriate

Comment: @LuisMendo Nope. That 1Mhz is used to sample 10khz which is the difference between the signal frequency and carrier frequency. So I'm not sure how to mix the 2 to get the sun and difference.

Comment: @user982209 But when you do `sig = exp(j*2*pi*fsig*t)`, you are actually sampling a 250-MHz signal with 1 Msamples/second

Comment: @LuisMendo I thought that's just a generating a signal at 250.01MHz frequency?

Comment: @user982209 It is a _sampled_ signal. Your time vector is discrete

Comment: @LuisMendo ok, what I'm trying to do is, generate a complex signal at 250.01MHz. And mix it with a carrier frequency at 250MHz. How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: @user982209 Generate those two signals with a sample rate high enough to fulfill Nyquist criterion. Then multiply (`.*`) and apply a lowpass filter (see `butter`).